# SharePoint List- Group Item/Row Level Security

Tags: list, security

I have a list of more than 4000 records for global sales team. I would like to set security permissions for viewing and editing according to the country column value. The issue is that I need to set the permissions for more than one user per record. For example, I need to give these permissions to the sales person and his manager who is responsible for different countries.

Any ideas on the best practices to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you need first create your groups for each **Country** create e.g (**English Viewers** & **English Editors** also **Frensh Viewer** & **Frensh Editors** ... etc) then you iterate for all your items in your list and check for each item the Country field if `currentCountryItem -eq "English"` share the two groups(English Viewer and Editors) with it and so on for the other countries.

> Note : For **Manger** there is to way to manage this requirement :
>
> 1. Add **Manager user** to the two groups or at least group Editor.
> 2. I prefere you to use this method because is the best practice so is to create another group and call it **Manager Group** and add it to each item with the two other groups.

Don't hesitate if you need more clarification.

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: May you please elaborate more on the use of PowerShell?

There is no future items... users will  only edit the existing records... no planned additions

Comment: Please find above the updated answer.